# Prevent Google Earth from generating MultiGeometry when loading KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a program that automatically generates KML files for use with Google Earth. My most recent output is pasted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
<Placemark>
<name>Active Location</name>
<address>60 NORTH WILLOW STREET, MONTCLAIR, ESSEX County, New Jersey</address>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

When this file is opened, a rectangular polygon is generated around the placemark, like so:

[image]

Saving the placemark as another document gives the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>QueryOutput.KML</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Active Location</name>
        <address>60 NORTH WILLOW STREET, MONTCLAIR, ESSEX County, New Jersey</address>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.2122552,40.8157007,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    -74.21556655758907,40.81321718180819,0 -74.21556655758907,40.81818421819181,0 -74.20894384241093,40.81818421819181,0 -74.20894384241093,40.81321718180819,0 -74.21556655758907,40.81321718180819,0
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Users must be able to collect the latitude/longitude data of the `Point`, which is then copied into another form. Because the placemark is defined as a MultiGeometry, they do not have easy access to this data. What changes need to be made to the initial KML file to prevent the placemark from generating a MultiGeometry? I've tried placing the `name` and `address` tags inside a `Point`, but that causes the coordinates to be set to 0,0,0 when the file is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When KML file has only an address, Google Earth will automatically do an address lookup to get an approximate location with a point and an error bounds with the box. Saving the KML after it opens in Google Earth will automatically add the location as a MultiGeometry to the feature.

Only way to prevent Google Earth from automatically adding the MultiGeometry to the KML is first adding a Geometry (Point, Line, etc.) to the KML. The alternative is to either edit the resulting KML in a text editor or manually do an address lookup in Google Earth then create a new placemark at the location it finds.

Searching an address in Google Earth
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148081?hl=en

Comment: When specifying the value as a Point (`<Point><address>...</address></Point>`), the coordinates are automatically set to `0,0,0`. Is there a way to force Google Earth to perform an address lookup on an `address` tag within a `Point` tag? The alternative you propose (manual lookups) is unfortunately what this system is being built to replace.

Comment: Address is not valid element of Point so would default to a location with lat=0, lon=0, etc.

Comment: In that case, is there an efficient/quick way to break a MultiGeometry down so that the Point's lat/long can be retrieved by users?

Comment: The Point is already part of the MultiGeometry and accessible to users. Right right-mouse click on the placemark and select Copy then paste resulting KML in a text editor to access Point....

Comment: That ends up being less efficient (and more complex) than just doing the manual search. Of course, that itself answers what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have KML with many addresses then Google Earth doing for you is more efficient. For single address then either way is about the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can prevent GE from creating that spooky output. When I deal with them, I follow the next steps:

1. save the output as kml.
2. format the kml using on-line tools (format xml tools).
3. convert xml to html and html to csv (no other way worked for me).
4. delete unnecessary data in the csv and use a GIS or GE to built the points again.